# Установка и начало работы с DOCTRINE 2

Tags: php, doctrine2

Установил я через compouser doctrine 2

```
{
  "require": {
    "doctrine/orm": "2.4.*",
    "symfony/yaml": "2.*"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-0": {"": "src/"}
  }
}
```

Создал, в нужном мне месте инициализацию коннекта к бд

```
public static function connect_to_db(){
        $config = new \Doctrine\DBAL\Configuration();
        $connectionParams = array(
            'dbname' => System::$SETTINGS->db->name,
            'user' => System::$SETTINGS->db->user,
            'password' => System::$SETTINGS->db->password,
            'host' => System::$SETTINGS->db->host,
            'driver' => System::$SETTINGS->db->driver,
        );
        try {
            System::$DB = \Doctrine\DBAL\DriverManager::getConnection($connectionParams, $config);
        } catch (DBALException $e) {

        }
    }
```

Пытаюсь выполнить в терминале

```
>php vendor/doctrine/orm/bin/doctrine orm:schema-tool:create
```

Получаю ответ

> You are missing a "cli-config.php" or "config/cli-config.php" file in
>   your project, which is required to get the Doctrine Console working.
>   You can use the following sample as a template:
>
> // replace with file to your own project bootstrap require_once
>   'bootstrap.php';
>
> // replace with mechanism to retrieve EntityManager in your app
>   $entityManager = GetEntityManager();

Да не хочу я создавать никаких config/cli-config.php, что он содержит и для чего нужен? Как мне установить doctrine??? Вот [ссылка](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/configuration.html) на официальный гайд установки. Я не хочу создавать никаких лишних файлов по типу bootstrap.php (при чем тут css либина и не знаю) да и не понятно, где его создать. + я хочу хранить модели в своем месте, а не непонятном src (где это вообще?)

Comment: во первых  bootstrap.php  никакого отношения к  bootstrap CSS не имеет

Comment: во вторых эти конфиги нужны чтобы библиотека понимала откуда брать настройки

Comment: @Rumato про bootstrap я в шутку. А про все остальное нет. Как я понимаю из гайда, он будет хранить модели в папке src, которая будет лежать в корне проекта? Это можно как-то поменять? Где должен лежать bootstrap.php? Что должно быть в config.xml?